# selectionchanged event is not firing

Tags: asp.net

when I am clicking on any date in calender, the selectionchanged event of calender is not firing.
here is my code

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
       Calendar1.Visible = false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please verify that the event is subscribing to the handler.
`<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1"   
           OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged">`

Comment: Yes. The event is subscribing to the handler. still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged with the event handler as bellow

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged
{

   TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
   Calendar1.Visible = false;
}
```